# Multiple class calculator

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple calculator using multiple classes.  I can make one in one class, but now I would like to try making one using two classes.  I am having trouble with calling some variables (fnum, snum, answer) from the OperationClass.
If I run the program as it's written now I get 0 returned for the answer.
I tried making the variables fnum, snum and answer in OperationClass public but that did not work.
Also I tried public class OperationClass extends Calculator.  That did not work either.
I know i'm missing something very simple.  I just can't pin point it.

**Calculator Class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OperationClass operationObject = new OperationClass();


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double userInput;
        int userChoice;

        System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
        userInput = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
        userInput = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please Select Operation to Perform:");
        System.out.println("1-Addition");
        System.out.println("2-Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3-Division");
        System.out.println("4-Multiplication");
        userChoice = input.nextInt();

        switch (userChoice){
        case 1:
            operationObject.addition();
            System.out.println();
            break;
        case 2:
            operationObject.subtraction();
            break;
        case 3:
            operationObject.division();
            break;
        case 4:
            operationObject.multiplication();
            break;
        }


    }

}
```

**OperationClass:**

```
public class OperationClass{

    double fnum, snum, answer;

    public void addition(){
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void subtraction(){
        answer = fnum - snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void division(){
        answer = fnum / snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void multiplication(){
        answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not initializing your `OperationClass ` instance members `fnum, snum`...

Comment: When putting code in a post, select the entire codes and click the '{ }' button at the top of the page. It'll avoid some parts being left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the values entered by the user to the `OperationClass` class.
There are multiple ways of doing this.

1) Option one. Change the methods to accept some parameters, for example:

```
public double addition(double fnum, double snum ){
      return fnum+snum;
}
```

and to get the result in the `Calculator` you can do this:

```
 case 1:
    System.out.println(operationObject.addition(userInput1, userInput2));
    break;
```

You have to store the user input in 2 different variables.

2) Store the user's input in the `OperationClass` as class variables.

```
public class OperationClass{
     .....
     public void setFNum(double fnum){
         this.fnum = fnum
     }
     public void setSNum(double snum){
         this.snum = snum
     }
     ......
}
```

and to pass the values from the `Calculator` you can do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ....

    OperationClass operationObject = new OperationClass();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double userInput;
    userInput = input.nextDouble();
    operationObject.setFNum(userInput);
    userInput = input.nextDouble();
    operationObject.setSNum(userInput);

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the very helpful answers.  It cleared a few things in my head.  I used the first option in Titus answer.  Can you explain something to me?  I understand what happened with your solution but what I don't get is how does userInput1 and userInput2 (System.out.println(operationObject.addition(userInput1, userInput2));) get carried to the addition method?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is what does return fnum + snum do?  Where is it getting returned to?  Also I created userInput1 and userInput2, when I pass those into the case statements, how does the program know to take  those two variables and add, subtract, divide or multiply?  Everything is working fine now i'm just trying to make sense of it all.

Comment: That method accepts two parameters (two `double` values) so when you call the method like this `operationObject.addition(userInput1, userInput2)` inside the method `userInput1` becomes `fnum` and `userInput2` becomes `snum` after the operation is executed (in this case `fnum + snum`) the result is returned to the place where the method was called, you can also do this `double return =operationObject.addition(userInput1, userInput2);`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting fnum and snum in OperationClass to anything, so their value is zero.  Delete those member variables, and change your addition() subtraction() etc. methods to take them as parameters, like this:

```
public void addition(double fnum, double snum) { 
    answer = fnum + snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to store the two inputed values to different variables, so the second won't overwrite the first:

```
System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
fnum = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
snum = input.nextDouble();
```

Once inputed, you can pass these variables to the `OperationClass`'s methods:

```
public class OperationClass{

    public void addition(double fnum, double snum){
        double answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void subtraction(double fnum, double snum){
        double answer = fnum - snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void division(double fnum, double snum){
        double answer = fnum / snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public void multiplication(double fnum, double snum){
        double answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the first and second `int`s as parameters. This involves re-writing your method objects to accept 2 parameters, or creating a constructor that accepts 2 parameters and instantiating the object **after** the numbers have been inputted.

To create the constructor, (which will allow you to set the variables in the class and use them):

```
public OperationClass(int fnum, int snum){
    this.fnum = fnum;
    this.snum = snum;
}
```

Then you call it when instantiating the object (again, **after** the numbers have been inputted) using:

```
OperationClass operationObject = new OperationClass(firstInput, secondInput);
```

You'll also need to modify your input so that the 2 inputs go in different variables. This is so that they can be passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You collect the two numbers into one variable called `userInput`.  The first gets overwritten by the second, then you never reference it again.  For your `OperationClass` to do something with those values, you should have methods to set the values, or pass them to the operation being performed as parameters.

For the first case you could add setter methods like this:

```
public void setFNum(double f) {
    fnum = f;
}
public void setSNum(double s) {
    snum = s;
}
```

Then in main, after getting a value from the user, set it using those methods.

```
System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
userInput = input.nextDouble();
operationObject.setFNum(userInput);
System.out.print("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
userInput = input.nextDouble();
operationObject.setSNum(userInput);
```

A second way is that you could make the methods in `OperationClass` take both numbers as parameters and never set it internally.

```
public void multiplication(double fnum, double snum){
    answer = fnum * snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```